# swiper pagination brakes after page change on jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, swiper.js

I'm using [iDangerous Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/) library to display a mobile swipe touch gallery in conjunction with [Jquery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) framework. 
It works fine except that if I leave the index page (where the gallery is) and then come back, the pagination widget doesn't work properly. It still appears (I can see the bullets), and it's still clickable, i.e. if I "touch" a bullet the gallery swipes to the correspondent slide and the bullet becomes "active", but it doesn't work the reverse way, in other words it doesn't respond to slide changes:  if I swipe through the slides the current active bullet does not update.

this is the initialization code:

```
$( document ).on( "pageshow", "#index-page", function( event ) {

    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
        pagination: '.pagination',
        paginationClickable: true,
        slidesPerView: 'auto'
    });

});
```

The page are linked with jquery mobile's **data-ajax="true"** attribute to preserve the global scope.

Comment: you should initialize it once only. Replace `.on()` with `.one()`.

Comment: or use `pageinit` event, which is called once

Comment: That solved the problem together with data-ajax=true property explicitly declared in links, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It help me pagination swiper idangerous jquery mobile

```
$(document).one("pageshow", "#page1", function (e) {
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        paginationClickable: true,
        hashnav: true,
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        hashnav: true });       
    function reinitSwiper(swiper) {
      setTimeout(function () {
       swiper.reInit();
      }, 500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**
Initializing the swiper twice.

**Solution:**
Define a global variable "swiper" outside the "pageshow" event. The global  variable "swiper" will be "undefined" on loading the gallery first time. When you leave the page and come back, global variable "swiper" will not be "undefined". Then do not initialize again.

```
<script>
    var swiper;

    $(document).on("pageshow", "#page1", function (e) {
        if (swiper == undefined) {
            swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                pagination: '.pagination',
                paginationClickable: true,
                slidesPerView: 'auto'
            }); 
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When you leave the page, the swiper variable with the value behind it are gone so it will be `undefined` and initialized again. Try using the local storage in order to preserve the value between the page loads.